# Reset Midori History Database

Tags: browser, history, browser-cache

After reinstalling my system but maintaining my home partition, whenever I launch Midori, I get a pop-up saying

```
The history couldn't be loaded: attached databases must use the same text encoding as main database
```

I can ignore the message, but it is quite irritating. How can I delete the data and allow Midori to generate a new one that it likes?

EDIT: For clarification, I am on a GNU+Linux system, so relevant file paths will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to circumvent it by deleting `~/.config/midori`. That folder contained all the Midori settings databases.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting history I would recommend editing the database (some knowledge of SQL is required)

goto `~/.config/midori` then open `history.db` in any sql database manager and delete the unwanted rows.

The best part is there are other databases in this location `~/.config/midori` where you can delete,edit or even include information.